# Unable to edit server side rendered block

Tags: block-editor, rest-api

I have a problem with Gutenberg block. I created block which pulls recent custom post type posts and display them as carousel.

I struggled with saving that block but I found info that I should use ServerSideRender in js file.

Now I have a problem in backend editor. When I add my custom block I'm unable to select it or delete.

Below the code of js:

```
const { serverSideRender: ServerSideRender } = wp;

wp.blocks.registerBlockType('wp-portfolio-manager/wppm-block', {
    title: 'Portfolio Block', 
    description: 'Block containing portfolio projects',
    category: 'common',
    icon: 'screenoptions',
    keywords: [
         'portfolio',
         'project', 
         'wppm'
    ],
    supports: {
        html: true, 
        align: true
    },
    attributes: {
        projects_count: {
            type: 'integer' 
        }
    },
    edit: ( props ) => {
        return <ServerSideRender block="wp-portfolio-manager/wppm-block"></ServerSideRender>;
    },
    save: (props) => {
        return null;
    }
});
export class Portfolio extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.props = props;
        this.state = {
            error: null,
            postsFetched: false,
            mediaFetched: false,
            posts: []
        };
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        let postes = [];
        fetch("/foobar/wp-json/wp/v2/foobar_post?per_page=5&_embed")
         .then(res => res.json())
         .then(
             (result) => {
                 result.forEach(function(item){
                    postes.push({ 
                        id: item['id'],
                        title: item.title['rendered'],
                        featured_image: item['_embedded']['wp:featuredmedia'][0]['source_url'],
                        url: item.link,
                    });
                });
                this.setState({
                    postsFetched: true,
                    mediaFetched:  true,
                    posts: postes
                    }
                );
             },
             (error) => {
                 this.setState({
                    postsFetched: true,
                    mediaFetched: true,
                    error: error
                 });
             }
         );
    }

    render(){
        const {postsFetched, mediaFetched, posts, error} = this.state;

        if(postsFetched && mediaFetched){
            let items = [];
            for(let i = 0; i < this.state.posts.length; i++){
                items.push(
                    <Project post={posts[i]}></Project>
                );
            }
            return <div className="wppm-portfolio">
                {items}
            </div>;
            
        }
        else if(error){
            return <div className="wppm-portfolio error">{error.message}</div>;
        }
        else{
            return <div className="wppm-portfolio loading dashicons dashicons-update"></div>;
        }
    }

}

class Project extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            media: []
        };
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        let medias = [];
        fetch("/foobar/wp-json/wp/v2/media?media_type=image&parent=" + this.props.post.id)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(
            (result) => {
                result.forEach(function(item){
                    medias.push(
                        {
                            url: item.source_url,
                            title: item.title['rendered'],
                            alt: item.alt_text
                        }
                        
                    );
                });
                this.setState(
                    { media: medias }
                );
            }
        );
    }

    render(){
        const { post } = this.props;
        const { media } = this.state;
        if(media === null || media == 'undefined' || media.length < 1)
            return <div className="portfolio-project loading">Loading</div>;

        let gallery = [];
        for(let i = 0; i < media.length; i++){
            gallery.push(
                <ProjectImage url={media[i].url} title={media[i].title} alt={media[i].alt}></ProjectImage>
            );
        }
        return <div className="portfolio-project">
            <div className="project-container">
                <div className="project-actions">
                    <span className="dashicons dashicons-search"></span>
                    <span className="dashicons dashicons-format-gallery"></span>                
                </div>
                <img src={post.featured_image} className="img-fluid"/>
                <div className="project-title">{post.title}</div>
            </div>
            <div className="project-gallery hidden">
                {gallery}
            </div>
        </div>;

    }
}

class ProjectImage extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
    }

    render(){
        const {url, alt, title} = this.props;
        return <div className="image-container">
            <img src={url} alt={alt} title={title}/>
        </div>;
    }
}
```

and here is the code of render_callback function in php:

```
function wppm_portfolio_block_render_callback($block_attributes, $content){
    if ( !defined( 'REST_REQUEST' ) || !REST_REQUEST ) {
        $projects = wp_get_recent_posts( array(
            'numberposts' => 5, //ToDo: Ilość z bloku (w bloku obsłużyć attributes)
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'post_type'   => 'wppm_portfolio'
        ) );
        if ( count( $projects ) === 0 ) {
            return 'No posts';
        }
        $elements = '';
        foreach($projects as $post){
            $featured_image = get_the_post_thumbnail( $post['ID'] ) == '' ? '<img src="' . __WPPM_IMG__ . '/placeholder.jpg' . '">' : get_the_post_thumbnail( $post['ID'] );
            $post_media = get_attached_media( 'image', $post['ID'] );
            $gallery = '';
            if(isset($post_media) && is_array($post_media) && count($post_media) > 1){
                $images = '';
                foreach($post_media as $image){
                    $image_tag = wp_get_attachment_image($image->ID, 'full');
                    $image_element = sprintf('
                        <div class="image-container">
                            %1$s
                            <div class="image-title">
                                %2$s
                            </div>
                        </div>', 
                        $image_tag, 
                        $image->title
                    );
                    $images .= $image_element;
                }
                $gallery = sprintf(
                    '<div class="project-gallery hidden">
                        %s
                    </div>',
                    $images
                );
            }
            $element = sprintf('<div class="portfolio-project">
                            <div class="project-container">
                                <div class="project-actions">
                                    <span class="dashicons dashicons-search"></span>
                                    <span class="dashicons dashicons-format-gallery"></span>
                                </div>
                                %1$s
                                <div class="project-title">%2$s</div>
                            </div>
                            %3$s
                        </div>', $featured_image, $post['post_title'], $gallery);
            $elements .= $element;
        }
        $result = sprintf('<div class="wppm-portfolio">%s</div>', $elements);
        return $result;
}
function wppm_portfolio_block(){
    wp_register_script( 'wppm_block', __WPPM_ADMIN_JS__ . '/block.js', array('wp-block-editor', 'wp-blocks', 'wp-element', 'wp-i18n', 'wp-polyfill', 'wp-server-side-render'), null);
    register_block_type('wp-portfolio-manager/wppm-block', array(
        'api_version' => 2,
        'editor_script' => 'wppm_block',
        'render_callback' => 'wppm_portfolio_block_render_callback'
    ));
}
add_action( 'init', 'wppm_portfolio_block' );
```

What should I do to make it selectable and removable on the backend editor?

Answer (score 1):

You've gone with a class based component and the normal solution for this problem is that **you forgot to use `useBlockProps`**.

Your edit component and save components do not use `useBlockProps`:

```
    edit: ( props ) => {
        return <ServerSideRender block="wp-portfolio-manager/wppm-block"></ServerSideRender>;
    },
    save: (props) => {
        return null;
    }
```

**Wrap your server side render component in a `div` and apply `useBlockProps` to that `div` and the problem should go away.**

Something similar to this:

```
<div { ...useBlockProps() }>
    ... etc
</div>
```

`useBlockProps` gives the opportunity for the block editor to inject event handlers and extra CSS classes. This is how it styles the selected block and handles the selection process, as well as things like animating block movers etc.

Also, be wary of class based components. WP hook APIs such as `useBlockProps` don't work with class based components. Everything you are doing here can be done with `useState` and `useEffect`, though it looks like none of your class based components are actually in use.

Comment: Do I need to switch entire code or only the base class (the top most which contains rest of objects)?

Comment: the component used for save/edit, your block can be selected, there's just nothing for the editor to attach event handles and HTML classes to for styling, that's the primary use for `useBlockProps` ( though not the only purpose )

Comment: for your API fetch, a `useEffect` should work, you can pass dependencies as a parameter so that it only fetches when those variables change. I would also be wary of polling the REST API that way, you should use the built in entities API, that way WP itself will handle state for you as well as fetching the data. At that point there's no need for any lifecycle or `useEffect` hooks in your code

Comment: Also `const { value, setValue } = useState( initialValue );`

Comment: To summarize in my case I need to switch only code of Portfolio class. The rest could stay as is. Am I right?

Comment: @bgolemba on closer inspection I'm struggling to find any use of the Portfolio component in your block, or any of the class based components. Your edit component uses a server side render component directly with no custom components, and your save component returns null. Is the code in your question complete? Or am I missing something? Where is `Portfolio` used?

Comment: I see now, your class based components are a red herring and can be ignored as you're not using them, I've updated my answer

Comment: I don't understand your comment. I'm new to React and blocks developping. I tried to write accordingly to React.js documentantion.
I try to explain my goal: I want to create dynamic block which pulls out chosen number of custom posts and displays them as carousel.
I want to use this block in editor to define by editor side how many of the posts should be pulled. 
The only documentation that I have found is the one about creating blocks in React.js.
I'm new to React but I'm expierenced in PHP programming so the server side solution would suit me well.

Comment: you have lots of classes in your questions code, but you don't use them anywhere, you could put the words to war and peace in your classes output and it would not matter. Your save function just returns `null` and your edit function uses a server side rendered output, so all this talk of lifecycle methods etc is irrelevant. The reason you can't edit your block is because your block has no editing UI and there is no code being run that interacts with the attribute you defined

Comment: e.g. there is no `<Portfolio>` or `<ProjectImage>` in your JS everything is done via PHP instead

Comment: also, look again at my answer and it's updates, the paragraph that says wrap your server side component in a div and apply `useBlockProps` is what you need

Comment: Ok thank you for reply. There is no use of Portfolio class because I had a problem with saving my block when I was using it in edit and save functions. 
I have read in other question here on stack that I need to use ServerSideRender if I want to use dynamic blocks such as this.

Comment: yeah, but you used api version 2 and forgot to use the `useBlockProps` hook, so none of the classes and event handlers that let you select the block are added. You need to use `useBlockProps` so the editor can add those in. Originally I thought you were using the class based components but I saw that's no longer the case, but you still need to use `useBlockProps` in your edit component, even if you use server side rendering

Comment: I did what you posted (in bold) but now the block loads empty (with text: "Block displayed as empty"). What now?

Comment: without knowing how you changed it there's no way for me to help, it's not enough to describe what you did in text, you have to show it

Comment: Unless you literally copy pasted what i put and replaced the entire edit component with just `<div {...useBlockProps() }>`, if you had done that then yes that would be the result, but that's not what I told you to do, _wrap/surround_ not _replace_

Comment: I wrapped out as you described in that way: 
`return <div {...useBlockProps()}>
             <ServerSideRender block="wp-portfolio-manager/wppm-block"></ServerSideRender>
         </div>;`